# how to change profile picture on yii2 backend advanced

Tags: image, upload, yii2

I am using yii2 advanced app . In that we have static profile pic in backend side. how to change that pic dynamically?? just like we change our profile pic in facebook and other social media. can we do this?

backend\views\layouts\left.php

```
            <div class="pull-left image">
                <img src="<?= $directoryAsset ?>/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image"/>
            </div>
```

how to change this image dynamically?

Comment: You have to write code for upload avatar and display it.

Comment: There were a similar question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274884/yii2-update-profile-photo